# React decoding special characters in string - is there any inbuilt mechanism or function

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native, decode

I am facing some issue with decoding ,i do have my text which have '& amp;' '& lt;' '& gt;' '&quot' and likewise
what i need is a function or anything in react that will decode these and give the correct ones , is there any plugin or dependency within react to do the same

For example

```
Text before decoding will look like I am &amp; learning &lt; react &gt; &quot
After decoding I am & learning <react>"
```

Can you guys help me in react way to solve the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function htmlDecode(input){
  var e = document.createElement('textarea');
  e.innerHTML = input;
  // handle case of empty input
  return e.childNodes.length === 0 ? "" : e.childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}

htmlDecode("&lt;img src='myimage.jpg'&gt;");
```